# Swift timestamp only 10 chars?

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

Im trying to push a timestamp from my app to a DB, The android dev is pushing up a timestamp which is 13 numbers long, But swift only seems to be outputting a 10 character timestamp.

How can this be achieved? This is my current method of generating the timestamp

```
let timeInterval = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

This will output

> 1531837161

But i wish to have it as the following

> 1532168517222

Any help or advise is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply it by 1000 :

```
let timeInterval = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Comment: Multiplying by 1000 means that you are adding 3 zeros to the number, which is not the expected result...

Comment: @AhmadF No it is not like that. The above code without Int will give 1532340116.81871. It is in seconds and you need to multiply it by 1000 to get it in milliseconds.

Comment: @AhmadF - Yeah Sharad is correct. Its Int64 that is truncating the decimal part. X1000 brings that in as it is desired here.

Comment: Well the issue is the question did not mention anything about seconds or milliseconds... I would assume that you should understand what's the thing that you are asking about before posting an uncleared question...

Comment: @AhmadF It is totally acceptable that this question might be unclear to many, but as I have faced the exact issue, I know that android gives timestamp in milliseconds while swift in seconds.

Comment: @SharadChauhan thank you for this solution! It seems to be working well, You are correct that Android does give milliseconds.. Thanks for the quick and easy solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I find very elegant.

```
extension Date {
    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
if let currentTimeStamp = date.toMillis(){
    print(currentTimeStamp);
}
```